# VB.net Linq datatable query

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datatables

I have a dataset that has has these columns and data that looks like this:

```
name :  path :           bow_Id :    midfront_Id :  midback_Id :  stern_id
gun1    guns\guns_1      0
gun2    guns\guns_1      0
gun3    guns\guns_1      0
gun4    guns\guns_1      0
```

Id like to use a string variable named 'key' to select one of the '_Id' columns and return only the 'path' that matches a passed string in the 'name' column.
I tried a few examples and gave up..

To fill the dataset I read in a XML string like so:

```
 dress_dataset.ReadXml(Application.StartupPath + "\WoWs_Scripts\" + s_name + ".xml")
```

here is some of the XML I'm loading:

```
  <JSB018_Yamato_1944.xml>
<sections>
<bow>
  <model>japan\ship\battleship\JSB018_Yamato_1944\JSB018_Yamato_1944_bow_ports.model</model>
    <node>
       <name>MP_JM025JSB018Bow_0_0</name>
       <model>japan\misc\JM025JSB018Bow\JM025JSB018Bow.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_JM026JSB018Bow_0_0</name>
       <model>japan\misc\JM026JSB018Bow\JM026JSB018Bow.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_JM029JSB018Bow_0_0</name>
       <model>japan\misc\JM029JSB018Bow\JM029JSB018Bow.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_JM033JSB018Bow_0_0</name>
       <model>japan\misc\JM033JSB018Bow\JM033JSB018Bow.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_JM109_Deck_Hatch_11</name>
       <model>japan\misc\JM109\JM109.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_JM310_Chrysanthemum_full</name>
       <model>japan\misc\JM310\JM310.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_CM086JSB018Bow_0_0</name>
       <model>common\misc\CM086JSB018Bow\CM086JSB018Bow.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>MP_CM087JSB018Bow_0_0</name>
       <model>common\misc\CM087JSB018Bow\CM087JSB018Bow.model</model>
    </node>
    <node>
       <name>HP_Fire_Burn_1</name>
       <model>UNKNOWN_ITEM</model>
    </node>
</bow>
```

I have a lot of entries in this data so if there is even a faster way to do this than ling that would be cool.
Thanks for the help
I should add.. if the column has a zero val, it is part of that section. other wise, its null.

Comment: Please show your attempt. What DB are you using? What objects are you using to pull the data - `ADO.Net`, `Entity Framework`, etc...

Comment: VB VS2013 win 7 app. My code is useless.. 
Let me update the question.

Comment: Wow, good job not answering any of my questions - which are necessary for your question to get answers. Showing your code tells your are not here to be spoon feed code and have given it an attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  You can use GroupBy() to group all same paths together than use a dictionary so you can look up by key

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("path", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("bow_ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("midfront_ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("midback_ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("stern_ID", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"gun1","guns\\guns_1", 0});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"gun2","guns\\guns_2", 0});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"gun3","guns\\guns_1", 0});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"gun4","guns\\guns_2", 0});

            List<DataRow> filter = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<string>("path") == "guns\\guns_1" )
                .ToList();

            //use dictionary
            Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("path"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            List<DataRow> guns_1 = dict["guns\\guns_2"]; 
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Let me give that a try.. I m getting no where fast here.

Comment: Hey.. thanks.. I converted this to VB and changed the first line.. I actually need to get the path from matching the input sting,name_ with column 'name'
If Im understanding this.. but this line hangs
       Dim filter As List(Of DataRow) = t.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("name") = name_).ToList()

Comment: You tagged the posting as both Vb.net and c# so I wasn't sure which language you really needed.  You converted the code correctly.  There is no reason it should of hung.  Do you have a dataset or a datatable?  If data set, then ds.table(0).

Comment: This works great..It was the system .. restart and all is good.. thanks :)